# Is there a way I can use explicit Read_uncommited isolation level in GridDB?

Tags: griddb

As per documentation, GridDB supports ReadUncommited Transaction Isolation Level. However, I wanted to know how can I use this transaction level explicitly. For eg: This is how we do it in SQL Server: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

I checked the documentation https://docs.griddb.net/architecture/database-function/#transaction-isolation-level and didn't find anything specific to my requirement.